# Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого

Tags: согласование

Добрый день!
Хотела бы уточнить,как правильно написать: поступило или поступили два обращения?

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта возможны. 
Я бы здесь чисто по восприятию предпочел бы первый вариант (поступило) для официальной речи и второй (поступили) - в обычном разговоре. Но это не строго, вполне можно и наоборот.

Вообще по поводу выбора варианта в подобных ситуациях существуют некоторые рекомендации, например - использовать множественное число для грусппы, воспринимаемой как целое (шли два студента), но единственное для разделенных случаев (в очереди к врачу стояло два пациента). Но я крепко сомневаюсь, во-первых, в правильности подобных советов вообще, и во-вторых, в применимости подобного разделения для такого объекта как "обращение".

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!!

Answer (score 2):

Пишем "поступило два обращения". На выбор ед.числа здесь влияют два фактора: неодушевленное существительное и препозиция сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!!